# Does LOC includes header files line count

Tags: visual-studio, lines-of-code

Does **code metric** tool of Microsoft visual studio 2010 counts the line of codes in header files included in the project.

Comment: Should be easy to test: add a few lines to a header file and see if the metric changes. Please report back with your findings.

Comment: yup.. understood... just wanted the information before hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code metric only work for managed code.

My code was a C++ unmanaged code so code metric is anyway not helpful.